# responsive - css parallax type - images not inside container

Tags: html, css, parallax, responsive

i am trying to build a site with basic css "parallax" effect where the image has a `background-attachment:fixed` and stays there when you scroll. the code `background-size:cover` works great in large browsers, but i am noticing when i make screen smaller, sizes 800px or 900px, the images in the div are getting cut off and i only see a little of the image. i've played with changing background-attachment to be `background-attachment:contain` - when i do that the image shows perfectly in the div but i see a huge space under the image.

http://greendental.mediaworksonline.com/

i've been wracking my brain on this for 2 days. if you could help that would be greatly appreciated. i'm building this to just use css and not jquery.

Comment: is the issue of the image being cropped in lower screen sizes related to aspect ratio of the image set as background-image?

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution can be put differents resolutions, an example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .imgblock {     
        min-height:400px;           
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .imgblock {     
        min-height:200px;                   
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: i seem to be using same code as you provided. found that on a site somewhere while searching.  the main issue is when i scroll down the size of site to say 900px the images are being cut off on left and right due to using the cover command. if i use contain it shows image correctly but then i have blank space above and below image.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle to see the problem?

Comment: greendental.mediaworksonline.com is latest code that has issue.

Comment: by css the @media screen and (max-width) is a solution, else you can use javascript to know the height of the screen and resize the imgblock